# Mongo DB aggregation not supping ISO date conversion

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

in below mention query when I am trying to use project1 "finish" and "planFinish"  to project2 and converting "String" date to "IsoDate" its showing "QUERY    [thread1] Error: invalid ISO date "

```
db.prOrder.aggregate(
[
{$match:{"enterpriseBid":"abc","prodOrderLineItems.planFinishDate":{$exists:true}}
},
//Stage2
{$unwind:{path:"$prodOrderLineItems",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:false}},
//Stage3
{$project:{prodOrderNumber:1,enterpriseBid:1,
 "planFinish":{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",date:"$prodOrderLineItems.planFinishDate"}},
  "finish":{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",
    date:{$cond:[{"$ne":["$prodOrderLineItems.finishDate",null]},"$prodOrderLineItems.finishDate",new ISODate()]}}}}
},
//Stage5
{$project:{prodOrderNumber:1,"enterpriseBid":1,"orderNumber":1,"finish":1,
  "planFinish":1,"dateComp":{"$cmp":[ISODate("$planFinish"), ISODate("$finish")]}}
},
//Stage6
{$match:{"dateComp":-1}
},
{$group:{"_id":{"orderNumber":"$prodOrderNumber","finish":"$finish","planFinish":"$planFinish"}}}
]
).forEach(function(doc){

printjson(doc);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution and it's working fine

```
//Stage5
{$project:{"orderNumber":1,"lastShipDate":1,"promisedShipDate":1,"dateComp":{"$cmp":[{
     type:Date,
     default:"$promisedShipDate"}, 
     {type:Date ,default:"$lastShipDate"}
 ]}}},
```